# How can jump to a C++ function's declaration with etags?

Tags: emacs, etag

I generated a TAGS file with etags, including several directories in the directory of a library I'm using. The command was something like:

```
etags *.h *.cpp /path/to/library/include/* /path/to/library/libsrc/*.cpp
```

When I call emacs' find-tag function `M-.`, I never get matches to tags from the `.h` files.

How can I jump to the **declaration** of a function from it's use in some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit on the late side, but function declarations are by default not included when building etags. Add `--c++kinds=+p` to include them:

```
etags --c++kinds=+p *.h *.cpp /path/to/library/include/* /path/to/library/libsrc/*.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `M-.` jumps to the definition. I've found that adding a prefix (`C-u M-.`) after jumping to the definition generally goes to the declaration.